# $L^{-1}$ in $LU$ decomposition relationship with $Q$ in $QR$ decomposition

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

Playing around with matlab, I see that the last row of $L^{-1}$ where $L$ is the part of the $LU$ decomposition is colinear with the last column of $Q$, in the matrix's $QR$ decomposition. Is there a reason for this?